# No such service ComponentInfo Android JobScheduler

Tags: android, exception, illegalargumentexception, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I'm trying to schedule a job with the JobScheduler, but i get an Exception as if I had not added the service in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{br.com.modeladoryoga.pontocorpofidelidade.ihm.servicos/br.com.modeladoryoga.pontocorpofidelidade.ihm.servicos.JobSchedulerService}
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1687)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
        at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:158)
        at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:42)
        at br.com.modeladoryoga.pontocorpofidelidade.ihm.servicos.JobSchedulerService.scheduleJob(JobSchedulerService.java:55)
        at br.com.modeladoryoga.pontocorpofidelidade.ihm.activity.SplashActivity$1.run(SplashActivity.java:31)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6111)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Build:

```
JobScheduler mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context
                .getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        JobInfo.Builder mJobBuilder =
                new JobInfo.Builder(idServicoNotificacao,
                        new ComponentName(JobSchedulerService.class.getPackage().getName(),
                                JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));

            mJobBuilder.setMinimumLatency(3000);

        if (mJobScheduler != null && mJobScheduler.schedule(mJobBuilder.build())
                <= JobScheduler.RESULT_FAILURE) {
            Log.d(TAG_SERVICO, "Unable to schedule the service!");
        }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

 <application 
 ...
 <service android:name=".ihm.servicos.JobSchedulerService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true"/>

 <receiver android:name=".ihm.servicos.NotificationServiceStarterReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
</application>
```

I have tried to run several times, clean and build without success. Anyone who has ever had the same problem could help me?

Comment: did you tried like this "new ComponentName(context,JobServiceClass.class)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `new ComponentName(Context pkg, String cls)`

```
JobScheduler mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        JobInfo.Builder mJobBuilder = new JobInfo.Builder(idServicoNotificacao,new ComponentName(context,JobSchedulerService.class));
        mJobBuilder.setMinimumLatency(3000);

        if (mJobScheduler != null && mJobScheduler.schedule(mJobBuilder.build()) != JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG_SERVICO, "Unable to schedule the service!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getPackageName()` as first parameter for `ComponentName()` :

```
JobInfo.Builder mJobBuilder =
                new JobInfo.Builder(idServicoNotificacao,
                        new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                                JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting the same error in android studio log cat but my application is working. Implement `Configuration.Provider` in Application class and override its method as given below in code snippet

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Configuration getWorkManagerConfiguration() {
        return new Configuration.Builder().setMinimumLoggingLevel(100).build();
}
```

using `.setMinimumLoggingLevel(100)` this method it resolved my issue.
if you are using workmanager then it gives error like this.

Answer (score 0):

**After**

`mJobBuilder.setMinimumLatency(3000);`

**Insert**

```
int ret = mJobScheduler.schedule(mJobBuilder.build());
if (ret<= JobScheduler.RESULT_FAILURE) {
      Log.d(TAG_SERVICO, "Unable to schedule the service!");
}
```